Why timeout ignore catchError in Nestjs microservice message sending?
I recently encountered some unexpected behavior in the code responsible for sending requests in my microservice. My primary goal is to handle prolonged requests, so I use RxJS timeout and catchError. However, TimeoutError ignores catchError and appears in the console, caught by the default NestJS exception interceptor. I know that I can use a global Interceptor to handle TimeoutErrors, and I have been using it, but to generate more detailed logs, I need additional context about the error, such as the transport name and method name. Here is my code:
return await firstValueFrom<Resp<TResult>>(
    this.client
        .send<Resp<TResult>, TMessage>(pattern, message)
        .pipe(
            timeout(this.rabbitMqTimeout),
            catchError((e) => {
                console.log(e)
                if (e instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    this.logs.log("service timeout error", {
                        service: this.serviceName,
                        method: pattern,
                        payload: JSON.stringify(message),
                    })
                } else {
                    this.logs.log("send to service error", {
                        service: this.serviceName,
                        method: pattern,
                        payload: JSON.stringify(message),
                        details: e.message,
                    })
                }

                return throwError(
                    () => new InternalServerErrorException(),
                )
            }),
        ),
    )

I see plenty of examples where timeout errors are handled properly by catchError, but not in my case. I am not familiar with RxJS at all, so I am really desperate for your ideas.
